# Error after commit on git repository Android application

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I have built one Android application, the name is Geo.

After that I created an account on Bitbucket, then I `clone`d the repository and I synced my project. After that, the project has some errors and the location changed: initially the project was stored in `D:\DropBox\Workspace`, but now after git sync the project is in `C:\michele\git\project`.

In the tab `Problems` I have 126 errors like this:
[image]

If I try to go on `Project properties` I can see this:
[image]

So I deleted this error link, clicked Add, selected google_play_services_lib clicked Apply then ok, but the error is the same and if I open this view, I can see the same error

Comment: Try checking `[] is library`, since you're importing a library

Comment: the error is the same, i check isLibrary, then click Apply, then OK. I re-open that view and I can see the same error

Comment: Try cleaning the project first

Comment: Yes, I have try to clean the project, restart eclipse but the problem is the same.
Now I have the project under c: and the library under d:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember I was once struggling with the same issue. 
How to fix:

1. Remove the library project and clean the Geo application project.
2. Import the library project in the eclipse (File > Import > Existing Android Code Into Workspace > choose the library project).
3. Now add the library project in the Geo application project.
4. Finally, clean the project.

It will be fine now!